# Copying large files to and extra internal hard drive

Tags: files, copy

Just installed Ubuntu on a 500 GB hard drive. I have another 2TB drive in that same computer that I am using as a backup of large files.

When I try to copy the file (~50GB) from an external WD drive into the 2 TB drive, I always get a permission error. I formatted the 2TB drive as ext 4 and later as ntfs but i still get the same result.

Is there any way i can transfer those files?

Comment: provide the error you receive and the effective permission of file and mount point of your 2TB disk

Comment: Double-check that the drive being written to is mounted writeable (rw) too

Comment: thank you for the response. i will post more information when i get back to work. the computer i was trying to fix is in the office. but i really appreciate your response